# HtmlEncode Isn't Encoding Properly

Tags: vb.net, html-encode

It doesn't appear that the strings are being encoded.

Issue:

```
Dim encodedStr As String = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<p>This is a test</p>")
```

The output produces:

```
<p>This is a test</p>
```

Expected result:

```
&lt;p&gt;This is a test&lt;/p&gt;
```

Comment: Works for me when I run it under the debugger.  How are you looking at the output?  Are you sure you're not looking at the value in HTML mode?

Comment: Good catch. That should've been my first hunch.. I'm passing an encoded string to an email application and I guess assumed the email was being sent as text

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  I've added my official answer so you can get your 2 points then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd double check to make sure whatever is displaying the value is indeed displaying it in text mode, and not HTML.  Under the debugger, it works fine:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<p>This is a test</p>");
"&lt;p&gt;This is a test&lt;/p&gt;"
```

(Yes, this is C# but the .NET framework code is all shared and I was lazy)